# What is the length of the diagonal of a square with side with length of a?

Tags: geometry

I'm working through calculus in a nutshell by George Simmons. This is question $17$ in the geometry section. I got  $a\sqrt {2}.$ The book says $\sqrt {2a}.$ How did the author get that answer?

Comment: was it written like $\sqrt{2}a$? it might just be a typo

Comment: *How* did you get $\sqrt{2}$? Clearly, it should depend on $a$... The bigger the square, the bigger the diagonal.

Comment: The book should say $\sqrt {2}a $ not $\sqrt {2a} $.

Comment: Your $a \sqrt{2}$ is correct but would look better if you used MathJax mark-up.

Comment: Oh, I didnvt see the "a".  In that case the OP is right.  ($a\sqrt {2}=\sqrt {2}a $ of course.)  The book with the a under the radical is probably a typo.

Comment: Damn, yes. I read it like "a \sqrt{2}" ("a" being an article), *not* "a\sqrt{2}". Mathjax helps.

Answer (score 1):

The diagonal cuts the square into two right triangles with the sides of the squares being the leg and the diagonal is the hypotenuse.

So let $d $ = the length of the diagonal and $a $ = the length of the side of the square.

So $a^2+a^2=d^2$

$2a^2=d^2$

$\sqrt {2a^2}=\sqrt {d^2} $

$\sqrt {2}*a=d $.

So you did it right and the book probably has a typo.  The $a $ needs to be *outside* the radical sign.

Comment: The OP's badly typeset answer of $a\sqrt{2}$ looks good to me.

Comment: @RobArthan I missedit too upon reading -- without Mathjax, what the OP wrote does look like  "a $\sqrt{2}$" instead of $a\sqrt{2}$.